Gif animation to start when "in-view" class exists
I added this code to my wordpress website so i can start the gif image animation when the dynamically added class "in-view" exists of the gif image parent element. But the gif animation doesn't work when the class "in-view" exists. Can anyone help? Many thanks.
https://minerva.thinkcreative.studio/what-we-do/research-development-innovation/
I added this code but it doesn't work:
    /* Start gif animation when in "in-view" class exists */

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    const gifs = document.querySelectorAll(".gif");
    
    function startAnimation(gifImg) {
    const gifSrc = gifImg.dataset.src;
    gifImg.src = gifSrc;
    }
    
    function handleMutation(mutationsList) {
    for (const mutation of mutationsList) {
    if (mutation.type === "attributes" && mutation.attributeName === "class") {
    const target = mutation.target;
    if (target.classList.contains("in-view")) {
    const gifImg = target.querySelector("img[data-src]");
    if (gifImg) {
    startAnimation(gifImg);
    }
    }
    }
    }
    }
    
    const observer = new MutationObserver(handleMutation);
    
    gifs.forEach(gif => {
    observer.observe(gif, { attributes: true });
    });
    });


